# Windows Batch File Recursion Through Directories to Process Files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

I'm trying to create a batch script that loops recursively trough directories and subdirectories finds all the .rtf files and converts them to .html

I have a program that makes the conversion like this: `rtf2html.exe file.rtf file.html`

This is my script:

```
@echo off
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
for %%f in (*.rtf) do (
    start C:\Users\User\Desktop\rtf2html.exe %%f %%f.html
)
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
exit /b
```

It loops trough the directories but doesn't output anything.

I think at the line `start C:\Users\User\Desktop\rtf2html.exe %%f %%f.html` it needs the paths for the input output files. 
I want to output the html file where the rtf is.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this in a folder with some sample rtf files inside subdirectories.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.rtf) do (
  "c:\folder\of\utility\rtf2html.exe" "%%a" "%%~dpna.html"
)
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. Didn't work, this is the output : `C:\Users\User\Desktop\File Folder Creater>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\rtf2html.exe" "
%f" "%~dpna.html"
Can't open input file!`

Comment: You didn't use the code I gave you.  Just change the path to `rtf2html.exe`

Comment: I did change the path, and I c/p your code, the output above is outdated

Comment: @Stefan  I can see the error in your message - which shows you didn't use the code I provided, but you changed whatever code you had.

Comment: The code is ok, the problem is the path, too long or the because of the diacritics. Question solved